# Google Deploy to App Engine disabled in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, google-plugin-eclipse

I am using the Google Plugin for Eclipse to deploy my project to App Engine, and this has worked great for over a year. But a couple of days ago it stopped working, and I can not seem to find the reason. The project is still an App Engine project, but the Deploy to App Engine button is disabled.

I already reinstalled the entire Google Plugin in Eclipse. I also added another GAE project, but then the button is still disabled. I managed to enable the button once to upload, but I don't know what triggered the enabling.

[image]

Has anyone seen this before and any clue on how to fix this?

EDIT: The button enabled when I removed and re-added the App Engine SDK from the build path of the project. After the deployment, the button disabled again..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known bug in the latest 3.9.1 release. The fix will be pushed on Monday, 5/2.

Answer (score 2):

The same thing is happening for my eclipse mars. The workaround I'm using is, File >> Close Project, then double click to open project, voila.

Comment: For me the Deploy button disappeared when I closed the project and re-opened it. :P

Answer (score 0):

The "Deploy to App Engine" only disables itself when I select another project.  So to get it enabled:

1. Deselect all projects (Ctrl+Click on the selected project - or restart Eclipse).
2. Select your project.

It should then be enabled (well, it was for me).

EDIT:  Google rolled out a new version of the plugin, and now the button works fine.

Answer (score 0):

For those who don't want to wait (I didn't), use appcfg. If you want to use External Tools, you'll find the executable in (SDK install - check configured SDK's)/bin/appcfg.(sh|cmd)

Set the working dir to the project folder, the commands are "update war", where 'war' is the location of the war directory relative to the project folder.

I set JAVA_HOME under the environment tab to the Java SDK, and PATH to the Java SDK/bin directory, and "replace native environment with specified environment" on Windows, worked fine without Environment settings on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Running Eclipse Neon 4.6.3 with no issue. To get it enabled:

1. Install Google Cloud SDK and Cloud Tools for Eclipse https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/docs/quickstart
2. Install components using the Google Cloud command line

   - `gcloud components install app-engine-java`
3. Convert eclipse project to a google app engine project

   - Right-click on project
   - Click on `Configure`
   - Click on `Convert to standard app engine project`
4. Make sure you click on the project and... voila!

Answer (score 0):

For me simple restarting of the eclipse did the trick.

I had closed the project by mistake and when I re-opened it, the deploy button was disabled.